# How can I redirect multiple servers to a single one with ssh?

Tags: redirect, ssh, server, iptables, forwarding

I would like to redirect multiple servers to a single one.

If a person wants to connect to the servers that are being redirected he needs to use a different port and username like maru@ip.ip.ip.ip -p 9393 for example.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make internal servers reacheable from the outside of your network, you want to look into remote port forwarding as described in [this link](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example#sec-Remote-Forwarding).

You will need to set `GatewayPorts` to `yes` in `sshd_config` and then start the forwarding with `ssh -R 9393:<remote ip>:<remote port>` on the outside-facing server (there are more advanced configurations to allow only certain clients described in the above link).

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will check that link out.

Comment: So after trying what you suggested it didnt work I set the GatewayPorts to yes in sshd_config and wrote ssh -R 9393:192.168.0.125:80 but I got a ssh usage with all the commands and such

Comment: Do I have to do anything in the Server that is being redirected to?

Comment: https://imgur.com/EJj0LA7 This is what I would like to do, I want to redirect all my servers to a single one but I tried so many stuff already I dont know what else to try.

Comment: Ok, I understood your question the wrong way (I though you wanted to have only the target machine as public facing server). If you want both srvA and srvB in the picture (https://imgur.com/RAZrLax) to redirect to the target server, you need to run `ssh -R 9393:192.168.0.125:80 srvA` (from any that can access `srvA`, but the easiest is to do it on `srvA`. (You then do the same for srvB).

Comment: Thanks for your help, sadly Im getting the same problem, https://imgur.com/14yTFDD

Comment: It appears you are writing the last IP with `:` instead of `.`, Have you tried `ssh -R 9393:192.168.5.132:80 192.168.5.132` ?

Comment: Woops, you are right, didnt see that, so after doing that I got this https://imgur.com/kkHVIi7 I tried connecting through my terminal but Im getting this Marus-Mac-mini:~ maru$ ssh 192.168.132
setsockopt SO_KEEPALIVE: Invalid argument
write: Broken pipe

Comment: Are you sure you did not want to type `ssh 192.168.5.132` ? The picture you sent is consistent with the redirection working, have you tried to connect on port 9393 ?

Comment: As the attacker I shouldnt know the port, so I will just use the default one. That said I want to make the attacked think he succeded even though he is being redirected to the other server

Comment: What you are doing with this `ssh -R 9393:192.168.5.132:80 192.168.5.132` is redirect all connections to `192.168.5.132:9393` to `192.168.5.132:80`. The first port number is the port from which you want to redirect from (i.e. what you called the default port). If you wish to redirect the ssh traffic, this should be port 22 (`ssh -R 22:192.168.5.132:80 192.168.5.132`)

Comment: I want to redirect the server to another server when the wrong port (22) is given, is it possible? Like, 132 to 133 if you give the wrong port, if you dont you connect to 132.

Comment: You want that, when you connect to `192.168.5.132` on port 22, you are forwarded to `other_ip` on port `x` ? In that case, the command should be `ssh -R 22:other_ip:x 192.168.5.132`.